# The program has unexpectedly finished after init QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

When I initialize QLabel like this;

xxx.h

```
private:
QLabel *label;
```

xxx.cpp

```
label = new QLabel("Some text");
```

I am getting error after run application (Unexpectedly finished).

However if I write nothing in header file just create it in cpp there is **no error**;

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel("Some text");
```

Could you please help me, why I cannot create object in header file. I need to reach and use it for another purpose too.

EDIT :

.h

```
#ifndef CAMERA_CONNECT_DIALOG_H
#define CAMERA_CONNECT_DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QtGui>

namespace Ui {
class CameraConnectDialog;
}

class CameraConnectDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit CameraConnectDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~CameraConnectDialog();

    void setCameraValidator();
    void setSDKParameterLayout();

private slots:
    void on_btn_resetToDefaults_clicked();

private:
    Ui::CameraConnectDialog *ui;

    QLabel *lblMethod;
    QLabel *lblYaw;
    QLabel *lblPitch;
    QLabel *lblRes;
..
..
..
```

.cpp

```
#include "camera_connect_dialog.h"
#include "ui_camera_connect_dialog.h"

CameraConnectDialog::CameraConnectDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::CameraConnectDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    setCameraValidator();
    setSDKParameterLayout();


}

CameraConnectDialog::~CameraConnectDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void CameraConnectDialog::setSDKParameterLayout()
{

    lblMethod = new QLabel(tr("Method"));
}
```

Comment: Do you initialize your label in constructor?

Comment: You are not creating object in header file, you are declaring it

Comment: @MuradTagirov In constructor I am writing label = new QLabel("text");

Comment: Could you please attach whole class declaration and .cxx code?

Comment: could you please post entire header file if it not very large and entire constuctor

Comment: @demonplus please see my edit.

Comment: Nothing wrong in these lines, the error is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Do you have labels with same object name in UI file?

Comment: @MuradTagirov there is no, If I write `QLabel *label = new QLabel("text");` in constructor or in `setSDKParameterLayout` there is no problem...

Comment: You are doing nothing else with this label later?

Comment: I will setBuddy with lineEdit and pass values

Comment: So, if create label in "setSDKParameterLayout" then you should initialize pointer lblMethod to NULL. And in setSDKParameterLayout please check pointer value first. If you are not using it it should be NULL.

Comment: I just delete from header file and create it from form with different name and setvisible false. Then I am calling `ui->lblMethod->..` my problem solved somehow

Comment: I think that Qt try to add  `QLabel lblMethod` to ui before it is initalized, you should try to create object before `ui->setupUi(this);`.